# Equivalence between $E_\infty$-spaces and connective spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It is well know that the $\infty$-category of group-like $E_\infty$-spaces and the $\infty$-category of connective spectra are equivalent, see e.g. 
May - "$E_\infty$-spaces, group completions and permutative categories" or
Lurie - "Higher Algebra", Remark 5.1.3.17

Now the category of $E_\infty$-spaces (here space means simplicial set) carries a model structure as well as the category of spectra. Is there a direct (left) Quillen functor

$E_\infty$-space $\to$ Spectra

whose derived functor restricts to such an equivalence? I have been unable to find a discussion of this in the litertatur. The only thing I can find are indirect functors going through $\Gamma$-spaces or related categories. The Bar-construction which is usually used is not left Quillen (!?).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an $E_\infty$ space?  If you have a particular $E_\infty$ operad in mind, then it depends which one you are using.  If you want a version of the category of $E_\infty$ spaces in which the operad is allowed to vary, you should state that as well.  Similarly, the precise answer will depend on your version of the category of spectra.

Comment: Take for example the Barrat-Eccles Operad and the classical (Bousfield-Frielander) category of spectra in simplicial sets. I was hoping that there might be an answer which is independet of the specific choice of $E_\infty$-algebra. But I want the Operad to remain fix.

Comment: I would have expected that a suitable version of the bar construction would provide a left Quillen functor.  Could you clarify exactly which version you are considering, and why it is not left Quillen?  (I would be inclined to use the operad from Steiner's paper "A canonical operad pair" to construct orthogonal spectra of topological spaces, but no doubt there are other possibilities, including some that are more simplicial.)

Comment: One way to make sense of 'restricting to an equivalence' is to consider the group-like $E_\infty$ spaces as a left Bousfield localization of the category of $E_\infty$ spaces. I think you just need to invert the map from the free $E_\infty$ space on $S^0$ to $QS^0$. The fibrant objects in this category will be group-like and fibrant replacement will be group completion. To do such a construction I would want the category of $E_\infty$ spaces to be left proper. This should follow from the $E_\infty$ operad being cofibrant, by Spitzweck's thesis.   

Comment: @Justin: This is actually exactly what I did. Just that it turned out that its easier to localize at a diffrent map than the inlcusion $S^0 \to QS^0$.

@Neil: I am actually in a hurry, I will comment on that later. But what makes you believe that the bar construction is even left adjoint?

Comment: The bar construction $B$ for a $E_{\infty}$-spaces is a model for the suspension functor $\Sigma$ (of coarse in the category of $E_{\infty}$-spaces). I think it is not a left Quillen functor. I would say that we have an adjunction at the level of $\mathrm{Ho}(E_{\infty}-spaces)$ between $\Omega$ and $B\sim\Sigma$.
I think that in the case of commutative topological monoids, the bar construction $B$ is a left adjoint to $\Omega$.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't localize at the inclusion $S^0\rightarrow QS^0$ but the map from $\mathbb{P}S^0\rightarrow QS^0$ adjoint to that map in the category of $E^\infty$ spaces. Here $\mathbb{P}S^0$ is the free $E_\infty$ space on the pointed space $S^0$.  

Comment: @Justin: Thats clear that you wanted to use this map. My objection is just that it seems hard to compute the function space $Hom(QS^0,X)$ for an $E_\infty$-space $X$. I am not saying that its not possible.

Thats why I would localize at the $E_\infty$-shear-map which is given by $Fr(a,b) \to Fr(a,b), a \mapsto a, b \mapsto a\cdot b$ for any binary operation in $E_\infty$ (here Fr means the free $E_\infty$-space).

Comment: @Neil: Sorry for the wrong statement. Peter demonstrated below how you can use a sort of Bar construction and you propably had this in mind. I just did it the wrong way when I tried it first. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, as several people have noted, the answer depends on
the choice of details.  There is a variant of my original passage
from $E_{\infty}$ spaces to spectra that certainly works, as was
noted in ``Units of ring spectra and Thom spectra'' by Ando, 
Blumberg, Gepner, Hopkins, and Rezk (arXiv: 0810.4535v3).

Take the Steiner $E_{\infty}$ operad for definiteness and 
denote the monad on based spaces associated to it by $\mathbf{C}$.
Take spectra to mean Lewis-May spectra since it is very convenient
to have the $(\Sigma^{\infty},\Omega^{\infty})$ adjunction for the
question at hand, and that is incompatible with symmetric monoidal
categories of spectra. Of course, that means I'm not using simplicial
sets, but I don't suffer from a prejudice in their favor: when I write
space I prefer to actually mean space.

Then, as discussed in modern terms in my 
paper "What precisely are $E_{\infty}$ ring spaces and $E_{\infty}$ 
ring spectra?'' Geometry & Topology Monographs 16(2009), 215--282,
the spectrum associated to a $\mathbf{C}$-space $X$ is the two-sided
bar construction $B(\Sigma^{\infty},\mathbf{C},X)$.  For cofibrant 
$X$, this is equivalent to the ``tensor product''
$\Sigma^{\infty}\otimes_{\mathbf{C}}X$, which is defined
by an obvious coequalizer.  This functor from $\mathbf{C}$-spaces to
spectra is left adjoint to $\Omega^{\infty}$. Further details are as
one would expect.

Comment: Thank you Peter, thats exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Actually I do not see a reason why this should not work for simplicial $E_\infty$-spaces and simplicial spectra....

Comment: Think about what $\Omega^{\infty}$ would mean in the simplicial world.
There are serious advantages to being eclectic.  For a different,
Segalic answer to your original question see Mandell, May, Schwede,
Shipley ``Model categories of diagram spectra'', especially \S 18.

Comment: I agree 100% with you comment about being eclectic. Its just that I got a situation where I naturally obtain simplicial $E_\infty$-spaces and thats why I was interested in them...